# GPS Track, computing height difference

Tags: android, c++, gps, android-sensors, lowpass-filter

I have implemented a GPS Tracker for Android. So far it is working quite nice but I have problems computing the **right** height difference for the track. I want to sum up all meters the device "climbed" and "descended". I do this in a background service comparing the current location object with the previous one and store the difference directly as a column in the database. If I sum this up after the track is finished I get a value that is approximately 2.5 times as high (1500m vs 650m) as measured with a bicycle speedometer that uses a barometer.

I know the measured altitude of the GPS device is inaccurate. Is there any way to "normalize" the measured altitude? Should I, for example, ignore all altitude changes below 2 meters? Another possibility would be to use additional sensors as some devices also have a barometer. But that would only help on some devices.

Thanks for any advice or hints on this issue!

EDIT 28.05.2013:
The answer of Bryce got me on the right track. I started searching the web and found a very simple low pass filter that is easy to implement. 
I did this in c++

A node class representing one waypoint:

```
class Node {
private:
    double distance;
    double altitude;
    double altitudeup;
    double altitudedown;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    long timestamp;

public:
    Node(double dist, double alti, double altiup, double altidown, double lat, double lon, long ts);
    double getAltitude();
    double getAltitudeup();
    double getAltitudedown();
};
```

Here is the function that does the actual work and computes the values for total ascend and descend:

```
void SimpleLowPass::applySLP()
{
    double altiUp = 0;
    double altiDown = 0;
    double prevAlti = this->nodeList[0]->getAltitude();
    double newAlti = prevAlti;
    for (auto n : this->nodeList)
    {
        double cur = n->getAltitude();
//        All the power of the filter is in the line
//        newAlti += (cur - newAlti) / smoothing.
//        This finds the difference between the new value and the current (smoothed)
//        value, shrinks it based on the strength of the filter, and then adds it
//        to the smoothed value. You can see that if smoothing is set to 1 then the
//        smoothed value always becomes the next value. If the smoothing is set to
//        2 then the smoothed value moves halfway to each new point on each new
//        frame. The larger the smoothing value, the less the smoothed line is
//        perturbed by new changes.
        newAlti += (cur - newAlti) / 20.0;
        std::cout << "newAlti: " << newAlti << std::endl;
        if (prevAlti > newAlti)
        {
            altiDown += prevAlti - newAlti;
        }
        if (newAlti > prevAlti)
        {
            altiUp += newAlti - prevAlti;
        }
        prevAlti = newAlti;

    }
    std::cout << "Alti UP total: " << altiUp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Alti DOWN total: " << altiDown << std::endl;
}
```

This is a quick and dirty implementation. But with a value of 20 for smoothing I get pretty good results. Still I will need to record more tracks and compare the results. Also there is Frame-Rate independent implementation on the website where I found this low-pass filter and I want to play with a moving average implementation.

[simple low-pass filter](http://phrogz.net/js/framerate-independent-low-pass-filter.html)

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: I would propose that the barometer is considerably less accurate than GPS. Further, are you sure that your bicycle altimeter tracks sum of all ascension/descensions, and not just the overall difference in elevation between start and end point?

Comment: @323go the barometer if far more accurate, but only for deltas.

Comment: I checked the deltas with a track that I created on an online mapping service. Got 720m for up and down, so the values of my bicycle altimeter should be pretty OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the barometer if the device has it, but either way you're going to have to apply a smoothing filter of some sort. Without looking at the data you're collecting, I can only speculate as to the cause, but it is probably caused from spikes when you lose sync with a satellite.

Comment: What I recognized with my data is that there many entries with minimal differences. As I see this is because of the inaccuracy of the GPS device. What kind of filtering/smoothing would you recommend for elevation data? I already use Douglas-Peucker to smooth my track (based on Lat/Lon)

Comment: I've experimented with several filters, but I haven't found the "killer" filter yet. The easiest to implement that still have decent results are low pass filters and box filters. Another option, rather than filtering is some kind of curve approximation. The curve approximation will over estimate ascent a little, while filtering will underestimate a little.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of low pass or box filters?

Comment: Sorry, meant boxcar filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function). You can implement it as a moving average where the window size is defined as the distance. I'd try that first, if the results still aren't good enough maybe consider hunting down a java library which provides FIR (finite impulse response) filters.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it got me on the right track, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

GPS altitude bounces around a lot, and each of these bounces looks like an ascent or descent.
In my experience the barometer sensor bounces around a much narrower range.

What you want to do is measure each climb (where a climb is defined as a constant increase in altitude), and sum the climbs to determine the total height climbed.

With any sensor (GPS or baro) the altitude will bounce around a little and we don't want those little bounces to be registered as short descents and climbs. So when we are climbing, we want to ignore small dips in altitude.

```
double THRESHOLD = 10;
Direction climbingOrDescending = Direction.NONE;

double totalAscent = 0;
double totalDescent = 0;

double climbStart;
double maxAltitude;

double descentStart;
double minAltitude;

public void onSample(double sample) {
    if (climbingOrDescending == Direction.NONE) {
        // First sample
        climbingOrDescending = Direction.CLIMBING; // Arbitrary
        climbStart = sample;
        maxAltitude = sample;
    } else if (climbingOrDescending == Direction.CLIMBING) {
        if (sample > maxAltitude) {
            maxAltitude = sample;
        } else if (sample < (maxAltitude - THRESHOLD) ) {
            // bounces in sample that are smaller than THRESHOLD are ignored. If 
            // the sample is far below maxAltitude... it is not a bounce, record
            // the climb and move to a descending state
            double altitudeGainedThisClimb = maxAltitude  - climbStart;
            totalAscent +=  altitudeGainedThisClimb;
            // Prepare for descent.
            climbingOrDescending = Direction.DESCENDING;
            descentStart = maxAltitude;
            minAltitude = sample;
        }
    } else { // climbingOrDescending == DESCENDING
        // similar code goes here to measure descents
    }
}

public double getTotalAscent() {
    if (climbingOrDescending == Direction.CLIMBING) {
        return totalAscent + (maxAltitude - climbStart);
    } else {
        return totalAscent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have difficulties understanding your answer :) Could you provide a real world example with some arbitrary data. I don't need any code just some figures that help understanding your idea

Answer (score 0):

When working with the sum of imprecise measurements, you'll always end up with a massive margin of error. It's a basic statistical certainty.

Instead of storing the difference between one measurement and the next, you should instead be considering each measurement as an independent data point. For instance, take the minimum altitude of all points, and subtract that value from all measurements.

Comment: My altitude measurements lie between 350m to 800m. What do I gain if I subtract 350m from all waypoints regarding the altitude deltas?

Comment: I only meant to stress that you shouldn't be storing the difference between individual, imprecise samples. However you want to post-analyze your data is up to you, but bear in mind that each sample should be an independent data point.